# Remove default http service check

Tags: icinga, icinga2

How can I remove the default http service check for agent-based servers? I already removed it on agentless but can't do the same for agent-based. Not all enrolled servers are webservers so an http check is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I went to my remote host and commented the http check in `services.conf` to disable the built-in http check. I wasted time configuring it at the master server when I should have been configuring my servers.

Answer (score 0):

The examples in `conf.d/` can be freely edited. They serve as general examples and ideas, but those apply rules inside services.conf will match more hosts with the same attributes of course.

One thing you should consider: Create your own config directory and include it inside icinga2.conf. That's done e.g. by the Puppet module with its own `objects.d` directory, or if you consider building a distributed environment, you will likely want to use the cluster config sync in `zones.d` anyways.

Some hints on that have been collected into the documentation a while ago:  https://docs.icinga.com/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/toc#!/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/configuring-icinga2-first-steps#your-configuration